# Вопрос по символу ENTER

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пишу программу с использованием математических операторов по книге. Возник вопрос (который возможно был уже задан): как правильно в условии if, символ b заменить на ENTER? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT(STR, VAR) \
    cout << STR " = " << VAR << endl;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    float u, v, w;
    char c = 0;

    while(true){
        cout << "enter an integer: ";
        cin >> j;
        cout << "enter another integer: ";
        cin >> k;
        PRINT("j", j); PRINT("k", k);
        i = j + k; PRINT("j + k", i)
            i = j - k; PRINT("j - k", i)
            i = k / j; PRINT("k / j", i)
            i = k * j; PRINT("k * j", i)
            i = k % j; PRINT("k % j", i)
            j %= k;    PRINT("j %= k", j);

        _getch();
        system("cls"); 

        cout << "Enter a floating-point number: ";
        cin >> v;
        cout << "Enter another floating-point number: ";
        cin >> w;
        PRINT("v", v); PRINT("w", w);
        u = v + w; PRINT("v + w", u);
        u = v - w; PRINT("v - w", u);
        u = v * w; PRINT("v * w", u);
        u = v / w; PRINT("v / w", u);

        u += v; PRINT("u += v", u);
        u -= v; PRINT("u -= v", u);
        u *= v; PRINT("u *= v", u);
        u /= v; PRINT("u /= v", u);
        _getch();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to try again? " << endl;
        cout << "if YES than press 'b'" << endl;
        cout << "if NO than press 'q' " << endl;
        cin >> c;
        if (c == 'q'){
            break;
        }
        else if(c == 'b'){
            system("cls"); 
            continue;
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "в условии if, символ b заменить на ENTER" - что это значит? Просто поставить `'\n'`? Или вы не об этом?

Comment: Сделайте нормальное форматирование и поправьте баланс фигурных скобок. Где у вас заканчивается цикл `while`?

Comment: @AnT, мне нужно при нажатии символа (с использованием клавиши ENTER), продолжить работу программы. в данной программе я использую символ 'b' и программа работает нормально, но, когда я пытаюсь использовать клавишу ENTER, ничего не происходит, только происходит переход на след. строку, если заменить на '\n'. Мне же хотелось бы, нажав ENTER продолжить цикл и работу программы сначала.
По поводу while спасибо!

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ по поводу "ничего не происходит".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша

```
cin >> c;
```

отказывается читать клавишу `Enter` потому что по умолчанию `std::cin` работает в режиме пропуска "пробельных символов" (перевод строки, пробел, табуляция и т.п.). Включите режим `noskipws` и `Enter` будет прекрасно читаться

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c;
if (c == '\n'){
  ...
```

Этот способ не поможет вам прочитать пробел или табуляцию, но как раз таки именно перевод строки вы им прочитать сможете.

Comment: благодарю за уточнение!

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, то проверка должна быть такой

```
 if (c == 'q') {
  break;
 }
```

................

вообще, правильней было бы написать так

```
while(с!='q'){
......
        cin >> c;
}
```

Comment: Да, это оно, только при написании этого кода, у меня ничего не происходит при нажатии клавиши "ENTER", только простой перенос на следующую строк, a у вас как?

Comment: @invzbl3 стоп, вы можете вообще убрать `else`

Comment: извините, я изначально не так видимо выразился, суть моего вопроса заключалась в том, что я во время запроса нажатия клавиши, прошу в своей программе нажать символ 'b' для продолжения работы, а хотелось бы заменить данный символ на обычную клавишу enter. но при ее использовании программа игнорирует enter и просто переносит на следующую строку.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал тогда нестандартную функцию `getch()`, потому что  `cin>>c` будет игнорировать все Enterы.

Comment: да? не знал, спасибо.

Comment: Ну так попросите его не игнорировать - и он перестанет игнорировать. Зачем лезть в `getch()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
c = getch();
if (c == 13){...}
```

коды клавиш

- 13 Enter
- 27 escape
- 8 backspace
- 32 space

Comment: Да, получилось теперь, спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что, успехов в обучении.

Comment: Безобразие неимоверное. Нестандартная функция плюс еще какие-то системно-зависимые "коды клавиш"...

Comment: AnT, почему безобразие?А как же таблица ASCII с использованием кода 13 для enter-a?
нашел вопрос похожего содержания на форуме- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9503/, но там советуют cin.get с использованием функции SetConsoleMode().

Comment: @invzbl3: Во-первых, языки С и С++ ничего не знают ни о какой "таблице ASCII". Во-вторых, в таблице ASCII никак не может быть кодов *клавиш*, поэтому никакого "кода enterа" там нет. В-третьих, код символа перевода строки в ASCII всегда был 10, а не 13. 13 - это код символа "возврат каретки".

Answer (score 1):

Получилось так в результате. Спасибо всем, кто отписался!

```
 int main()
    {
        int i, j, k;
        float u, v, w;
        char c = 0;

        while(true){
            cout << "enter an integer: ";
            cin >> j;
            cout << "enter another integer: ";
            cin >> k;
            PRINT("j", j); PRINT("k", k);
            i = j + k; PRINT("j + k", i)
                i = j - k; PRINT("j - k", i)
                i = k / j; PRINT("k / j", i)
                i = k * j; PRINT("k * j", i)
                i = k % j; PRINT("k % j", i)
                j %= k;    PRINT("j %= k", j);

            _getch();
            system("cls"); 

            cout << "Enter a floating-point number: ";
            cin >> v;
            cout << "Enter another floating-point number: ";
            cin >> w;
            PRINT("v", v); PRINT("w", w);
            u = v + w; PRINT("v + w", u);
            u = v - w; PRINT("v - w", u);
            u = v * w; PRINT("v * w", u);
            u = v / w; PRINT("v / w", u);

            u += v; PRINT("u += v", u);
            u -= v; PRINT("u -= v", u);
            u *= v; PRINT("u *= v", u);
            u /= v; PRINT("u /= v", u);
            _getch();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to try again? " << endl;
            cout << "if YES than press 'ENTER'" << endl;
            cout << "if NO than press 'q' " << endl;

            c = _getch();
            if(c == 'q'){
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 13){
                system("cls"); 
                continue;
            }
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Нет, ни в коем случае. Не надо бездумно смешивать C++ потоковый ввод/вывод, С ввод/вывод и, тем более, нестандартный ввод-вывод в одной программе.

Comment: Это книжный пример. Я лишь добавил if else и нижних 3 сточки
 
cout << "Would you like to try again? " << endl;...

Верхние cout/cin и макрос были использованы в самом примере.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Если это "книжный пример", то почему такой мешанины не было в вашем оригинальном варианте?

Comment: если не считать добавленных 3 cout-а и кусок с if else,то остальное было дано.

Answer (score 0):

Код Enter - 13
Просто введи 13 в нужное месте KappaPride

Comment: В данном случае я так и сделал.